# Error in Java Generics - Required type: List<MyClass> Provided: List<T>

Tags: java, generics

I have two classes implementing interface

```
public class MyClassA implements IClassA {
   // code
}

public class MyClassB implements IClassB {
   // code
}
```

I have Utility function to convert these classes

```
public class Util {
    public static List<MyClassB> convertAtoB(List<MyClassA> aClasses) {
             // logic
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a generic class

```
public class GenericClass <D extends IClassA, V extends IClassB> {
    public List<V> someFunc(List<D> in) {
         return Util.convertAtoB(in);   // ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

The error is coming as

```
Required Type: List<MyClassA> 
Provided: List<D>
```

**What is going wrong ?**

**EDIT**

Here is what I want to achieve

I have many converter functions which convert one type of list to another using some logic. Functions look like below and are in Util class

```
List<B> convertAtoB(List<A> list) { }
List<C> convertBtoC(List<B> list) { }
List<D> convertCtoD(List<C> list) { }
List<E> convertDtoE(List<D> list) { }
... so on
```

Now, all these have to be invoked Asynchronously. So, I will use AyncTask for this purpose. Now I have two options:

**Option-1:** Create multiple classes each extending AsyncTask and calling respective converter function in each of them.

```
class ConvertAtoBAsync extends AsyncTask<List<MyClassA>, Void, List<MyClassB>> {
     public List<MyClassB> doInBackground(List<MyClassA> ...lists) {
           return convertAtoB(lists[0]);
     }
}

class ConvertBtoCAsync extends AsyncTask<List<MyClassB>, Void, List<MyClassC>> {
     public List<MyClassC> doInBackground(List<MyClassB> ...lists) {
           return convertBtoC(lists[0]);
     }
}

.. so on
```

**Option-2:** Create a generic AsyncTask class which can invoke a particular type of converter based on class type

```
public class ConvertAsync <D extends IClassIn, V extends IClassOut> {
          
        ConvertAsync(Class _class) {  mClass = _class }

        public List<V> someFunc(List<D> in) {
             if(mClass = MyClassA.class)
                   return Util.convertAtoB(in);   // ERROR HERE
             else if(mClass = MyClassB.class)
                   return Util.convertBtoC(in);   // ERROR HERE
             .. so on
        }
    }
```

**Can I not achieve using Option-2 ?**

Comment: Well, you've given wrong parameters and the compiler isn't happy about it. I don't know why you would think that the unbound generic type parameter `D` is the same as `MyClassA`?

Comment: `D` IS-A `IClassA` and `MyClassA` IS-A `IClassA`, but that doesn't mean that you can pass a `D` where you need a `MyClassA`. `IClassA` could have many other implementations.

Comment: @Kayaman The there is a additional code to know the type. And if type is MyClassA, then above code would be invoked, else something else and so on.. Can't this be done ?

Comment: You will need to explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: @tgdavies Actually read my above comment, suppose there is additional code to know the type and on being sure, the function wud be invoked, else some other function wud be invoked..

Comment: @tgdavies I have a converter functions which convert one type of list to another. And this is to be performed Async. So option-1 wud be to make Async classes as many as there are converters. Option-2: Make one generic Async class and use above-kind-of-code.

Comment: You will need to explain clearly and in detail what you want to achieve.

Comment: You have written a conversion function which converts only one type of list, then called it from a context where the list may contain other types. What do you expect that to do? Why have the generic type parameters on GenericClass when the code in the class only works with MyClasA and MyClassB?

Comment: @tgdavies I have edited question to include detailed version. Pls check

Comment: `class Child extends Parent` means *Child < Parent*, but `List<Child>` and `List<Parent>` do not have the same subtype relationship. In fact, they have no such relationship. thus, `List<D>` is *not* a subtype of `List<MyClass>`, even if `D` has `MyClass` as bound.

Comment: Have you checked whether the code you're trying to write makes any sense? I've seen this kind of conversion code before (with the same generics confusion), but this is the first time I've seen `Async` in there, and that kinda makes me wonder what kind of "ultimate conversion system" you're building.

Comment: If you are convinced at one point in your code that in really is a List<MyClassA> then you can cast it.

Comment: @tgdavies you mean cast a generic to proper type like this `(List<MyClassA>)in`

Comment: Yes, obviously it is unsafe to do so, but if you trust that the correct converter is being used, you can cast the list.

Comment: @SimpleGuy What is wrong with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63115388/6505250) so that you did not accept it?

Answer (score 4):

With Java Generics, where a `List<MyClassA>` is expected, you must provide a `List` of exactly that element type, e.g. an `ArrayList<MyClassA>`, not e.g. an `ArrayList<MySubClassA>`.

Additionally, in `Util` you require the parameter to be a `List<MyClassA>`, not using the interface `IClassA`.

So, when you try to pass `List<D>` to your `Util` method, the compiler rejects that for two reasons:

- The method requires `MyClassA` elements, and the `List<D>` only can only guarantee elements of the interface type `IClassA` which might as well come from a different `MyOtherClassA`.
- Even without that difference, a method requiring `List<IClassA>` will not accept a `List<MyClassA>`, even given tha fact that `MyClassA` implements `IClassA` (see below for rationale).

So you should change the `Util` method to accept `List<? extends IClassA>`.

**Rationale**

Inside the method, you might try to store something into that list. The method sees a type of `List<IClassA>`, so storing a `MyOtherClassA` instance would look perfectly okay. But actually you passed in a `List<MyClassA>`, and now this list gets corrupted with an element not being of type `MyClassA`. So, Java was designed not to allow that, and the compiler is correct in flagging that as an error situation.

By declaring `List<? extends IClassA>`, you allow using `List<MyClassA>` as an actual argument, and at the same time effectively prohibit storing into that list, inside the method.

**EDIT:**

You added more context to your question. Still, my advice is to modify the `Util` methods to accept `List<? extends IClassA>` and similar. That sould be the main element to make Option 2 work.

Comment: More details here too with a lot of examples/explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super - your method `convertAtoB(List<MyClassA> aClasses)` is invariant but you want it to be "covariant" as described above